# Ajax field in products page

Tags: commerce

I have downloaded the Commerce Kickstart distro. In the product page there is a quantity field which you can use to enter your custom value; I want to display the total cost of current product in AJAX. Is it possible?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/86750/41418 It gives you a new price on changed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such default functionality in drupal commerce.

[Commerce Cart Ajax](http://drupal.org/project/dc_cart_ajax)

This module will ajaxify your cart page. If you need this in product detail page then you can build a custom module for that with [Ajax Api in Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)