# How can I dynamically refresh the price on product page when changing quantity based on price table

Tags: ajax, commerce

I'm currently building a web store with Drupal commerce and would like to get to price shown on a product page to asynchronously refresh when the user increases the amount in the quantity field, such as [here](https://www.opensesame.com/c/pandemic-flu%E2%80%94how-prevent-and-respond-training-course?from=CardTitle).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

[Commerce Cart Ajax](https://drupal.org/project/dc_cart_ajax)

> **Features**
>
> 1. The “remove” button on cart view removes the item from the cart
>      immediately, without a page refresh. The row is removed from the
>      table.
> 2. The “Qty” is updated when the "update" button is clicked. The totals are recalculated. No page refresh.

Comment: Thank you but this is actually not my question. As you can see on the link I gave this is about the "productdisplay page" and not the cart.

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53990/ajax-field-in-products-page-drupal-commerce

Answer (score 1):

You can show the price in the add to cart form using this approach:

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
*/
function MODULE_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
  // Add read only price field to add to cart form
  if (isset($form_state['default_product']->commerce_price)){
    $price = commerce_product_calculate_sell_price($form_state['default_product']);
    $form['display_price'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Price'),
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => commerce_currency_format($price['amount'], $price['currency_code']),
      '#prefix' => '<div class="display-price">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
  }
}
```

It may need adjusting to include the quantity multiplier, but should provide a good starting point there.